# Modify GraphQL output format

Tags: php, graphql

I am trying to move some of our REST endpoints to GraphQL. I am using the library at [GraphQL](https://github.com/Youshido/GraphQL). Looks like the output is always in the form:

```
{
   data: { currentTime: "2016-05-01 19:27pm" }
}
```

I would like to get the data in the following form:

```
{
  status: "ok",
  data: { currentTime: "2016-05-01 19:27pm" }
}
```

i.e, return the status of the request , either "ok" or "error", mostly because current client code uses this convention. Is there any way to achieve this? I can consider using other library too.

Comment: "Is there any way to achieve this?" -- that is not valid JSON, and so it is unlikely that any GraphQL server code will generate that response. If you add a comma after `"ok"`, and make it be valid JSON, then your proposed response merely goes against [the official GraphQL response format recommendation](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/). You may have difficulty finding a library that would add a `status` field in for you. You might be able to find a library that gives you the JSON response that it generates, to which you add your `status` field.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo of course

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you'll have to add the status yourself, as this is not standard GraphQL response format.

However, GraphQL response does contain an optional `errors` field, which will be included in the response in case of an error, you can use it's existence as an indication of a problem.